# Is there any way to stop the 'log window full' message in SAS

Tags: sas, logfile

Are there any settings I can apply to a SAS session so that I will never get the 'log window is full' message?

I'd still like the log to be written to the log window - I just don't want to receive the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the size of the log with the DMSLOGSIZE option, but that only goes up to 999,999 (default is 99,999):
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#base-sysop-dmslogsize.htm

I don't think you can make it larger than that.  The other thing you may be able to do is save it to a file; if you do that, it may allow the log to grow larger than that, but I don't think it will allow you to see more than that many rows in the log viewer.  I'd definitely move this Q to SAS-L as if there is a better solution, one of those folks will know.